# Quick question about Lua stand-alone interpreter

Tags: c, function, lua, interpreter

I saw this function in the `lua.c`  file called `dotty()`. I have a feeling that it takes line-by-line input, is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you read the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, it's basically the [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL).

That function technically works on a chunk-by-chunk basis. The `loadline` function does the actual line-by-line input, until it gets a complete chunk to execute.